# PHP MySQL Group By Using given array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
************************************************
* id  *  location                   *  status  *
************************************************
* 1   *  Shah Alam, Selangor        *  1       *
* 2   *  Seri Kembangan, Selangor   *  1       *
************************************************
```

Hello guys, i have this kind of table in my database. Which in the location field, there is state. As you see, in the current field is Selangor.

How do i group it by Selangor and count it? I'm not sure whether using substr in mysql query is better or not. I do have an array which i think also possible to use to group and count.

```
$negeri = array('Selangor','Kedah','Johor','Negeri Sembilan','Perlis','Perak','Sarawak','Sabah','Kuala Lumpur','Kelantan','Terengganu','Melaka','Pahang','Pulau Pinang');
```

If i am about to use this array solution, how do i do it? Thanks

Comment: Why do not to try normalization?

Comment: you should split location in to two

Comment: You'd be better served to just have two columns for location: city and state. Then you can group by state.

Comment: Can you put here your expected output?

Comment: @MarkM .. the previous programmer make the field like that. The data now contain more than 100 thousands.. i have to find a simple solution for this.

Comment: @Sadikhasan the output i expect is like below :

Country | Total
Selangor | 2

Comment: @sectus How do i do that? care to explain? Thanks

Comment: `select * from Tbl_name where location LIKE '%Selangor%' group by location;` will return results contain `Selangor` string in `location`. Now can count number of rows return in php.

Comment: @CJRamki, the field now contain other than 'Selangor' too. Like Kedah, Johor and etc. I need all to be done in one query, and expected the result all group by state.

Comment: @MuhamadAzam I posted my answer below. You want all counts in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sql query,

```
select count(location) as locCount from state where location LIKE '%Selangor%' group by location;
```

**in PHP**

```
$sql = "select count(location) as locCount from state where location LIKE '%".$negeri[0]."%' group by location;";
```

Replace `$negeri[0]` with your variable name in php

**EDIT: TO CREATE SQL QUERY IN LOOP TRY THIS CODE**

as per @massquote's code, you can create a sql query in loop like below,

```
$negeri = array('Selangor','Kedah','Johor','Negeri Sembilan','Perlis','Perak','Sarawak','Sabah','Kuala Lumpur','Kelantan','Terengganu','Melaka','Pahang','Pulau Pinang');
$sql = "SELECT ";
$i=1;
$totCount = count($negeri);
foreach($negeri as $place){
  $sql .= "SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%".$place."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place".$i;
  if($i != $totCount) {
    $sql .=", ";
  }
  $i++;
}
$sql .= " FROM state;";
echo $sql;
```

`echo $sql` will print the below `sql query`, you can use final `$sql` variable as `sql query`.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Selangor%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Kedah%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Johor%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place3, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Negeri Sembilan%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place4, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Perlis%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place5, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Perak%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place6, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Sarawak%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place7, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Sabah%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place8, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Kuala Lumpur%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place9, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Kelantan%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place10, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Terengganu%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place11, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Melaka%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place12, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Pahang%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place13, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN location LIKE '%Pulau Pinang%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as place14 
FROM state;
```

Comment: @cj-ramkl How do i group the location and show the sum? Do i need to group by the array given?

Comment: it will return each location's sum in separate column like `place1, place2,... placex`. So, number of columns is depends upon your array length. In this example I used your `$negeri`. It contains 14 locations in array. So, It is returning `place1` to `place14` as a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
SELECT 'Selangor' as state,
    SUM(CASE WHEN location like '%, Selangor%' then 1 Else 0 end) AS cnt from yourtable 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Kedah' as state,
    SUM(CASE WHEN location like '%, Kedah%' then 1 Else 0 end) AS cnt from yourtable;
```

Just generate the sql using loop in php then execute the script.